# Sending UDP to a host that is frequently down

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the condition where I am sending telemetry data to host via that is often down. This is not strictly true, but the client is out of range of the host network often.  The python datagram warns me that the host is down; however, I am aware of this.

Is there a best practice in python to send data to a host that is down most of the time?

I currently have to catch the exception or there's an error, but I know this to be the case.

```
        try :
            sockudp.sendto(data, (UDP_IP, port))
        except Exception as e:
        #    print(e)
            pass
```

Comment: Of course you should catch the exception, and probably log it too. Just because you know it's down most of the time doesn't mean you won't want to know if it's down all of the time or more of the time. You shouldn't just catch the broad `Exception` though, you should catch the specific one (`socket.error` I think?).

Comment: Also don't forget about the guy who takes over this code after you quit, he probably wants to know whether it's down also.

Comment: Definitely don’t leave that Except...pass as it is, that’s a recipe for invisible errors, and no software author wants invisible errors.